# How to update whole output row on change of given Input?

Tags: android, tablerow

I am having trouble with my output screen!

When I click on `Click` button with these inputs output screen looks like attached image, which is so far great!

[image: With first inputs output comes like this]

But if I change my input, the program gives new answer by adding more rows with previous answers! I want only new answers on screen to be shown!
Also without updating input if I click on button same way screen adds up new rows!
I am including a picture of this also..

[image: Screen when input updated]

I used this code given below,

```
clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aI = Double.parseDouble(Ia.getText().toString());
                bI = Double.parseDouble(Ib.getText().toString());
                cI = Double.parseDouble(Ic.getText().toString());
                bisection();
            }
        });

private void bisection() {

        if ((f(aI) < 0 && f(bI) > 0) || (f(aI) > 0 && f(bI) < 0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cI; i++) {

                View tableRow = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_item, null, false);
                TextView iteration = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.index);
                TextView a = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.a);
                TextView b = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.b);
                TextView x = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.x);
                TextView fx = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.fx);

                double root = (aI+bI)/2;

                iteration.setText(" " + (i + 1));
                a.setText(Double.toString(aI));
                b.setText(Double.toString(bI));
                x.setText(Double.toString(root));
                fx.setText(Double.toString(f(root)));
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

                if(f(aI)*f(root) < 0){
                    bI = root;
                }else if (f(aI)*f(root) >0) {
                    aI = root;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.popUpMsg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static double f(double x){
        return ((Math.pow(x,3))-x-4);

    }
```

I have already found almost same problem has been solved in a post previously asked by someone else but I couldn't fix mine! Help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button click listener method, add following line of code before calling bisection().

```
tableLayout.removeAllViews();
```

Whenever, you will click the button, previous output will be removed before calculating new input values.

Your code would look like this:

```
clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            aI = Double.parseDouble(Ia.getText().toString());
            bI = Double.parseDouble(Ib.getText().toString());
            cI = Double.parseDouble(Ic.getText().toString());
            tableLayout.removeAllViews();  // Remove previous output
            bisection();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But another Question is, My header row gets disappeared now after Click on the button!
Header row means,
Iteration | a | b | x | fx
how can i solve?

Comment: Hey, it got solved Actually :D 
added that header row by writing,
tableLayout.addView(headerRow); before tableLayout.removeAllViews();
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @tasfi Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

first way; You have to use

```
removeAllViews();
```

Before adding. To do this, you have to have a layout variable around. ex;

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

Another way is adding the Textviews in the beginning with VIEW.INVISIBLE or VIEW.GONE

Whichever suits you.

Comment: Thank You so much! 
I was confused where to use it but  then got it :)

Comment: Actually, in programming point of view, deleting VIEWs in not a good idea. You can reuse them by, setting VISIBLE and INVISIBLE.

Comment: Thank  You, I will experiment this trick in my code :) @kelalaka